# How to prove the following theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h$ be a real valued function on $[0,\lambda]$ with $\lambda>0$ satisfying :$h(\theta\alpha)<\theta h(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in (0,\lambda),\;\theta \in (1,\frac{\lambda}{\alpha}]$. Then we have : $$h(\lambda)<h(\alpha)+h(\lambda-\alpha),\quad\text{for all}\;\alpha \in (0,\lambda).$$

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: I have modified the above question.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: write $h(x) = x \varphi(x)$.

Answer (score -1):

Write $\alpha$ as $t\lambda$, where $t$ is between $0$ and $1$, and set $\theta=t^{-1}$, then we get
$$f(\alpha)+f(\lambda-\alpha)=f(t\lambda)+f((1-t)\lambda)>tf(\lambda)+(1-t)f(\lambda)=f(\lambda)$$